# Plotly Dash in Jupyter notebook gives "gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash

I am new to the dash library and ran a simple example from the link :
[Medium article](https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-jupyterdash-811f1f57c02e).
I wanted to run dash plotly in jupyter notebook but this simple example gives me an error.
Dash is installed properly since the below code does not give any error

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
```

On running the example, I get:

```
Exception in thread Thread-20:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_dash/jupyter_app.py", line 289, in run
    super_run_server(**kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1717, in run_server
    self.server.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1005, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 848, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 456, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 470, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    137             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 138                 (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    139 

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     74 
---> 75     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     76         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    744     addrlist = []
--> 745     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    746         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, **response_kw)
    593                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 594                                                   chunked=chunked)
    595 

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    360         else:
--> 361             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    362 

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1271         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1272         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1273 

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1317             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1318         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1319 

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1266             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1267         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1268 

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1037         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1038         self.send(msg)
   1039 

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in send(self, data)
    975             if self.auto_open:
--> 976                 self.connect()
    977             else:

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    162     def connect(self):
--> 163         conn = self._new_conn()
    164         self._prepare_conn(conn)

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    146             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 147                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    148 

NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f46d007e940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    422                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 423                     timeout=timeout
    424                 )

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, **response_kw)
    642             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 643                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    644             retries.sleep()

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    362         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 363             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    364 

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='x86_64-conda-linux-gnu', port=9095): Max retries exceeded with url: /_alive_34d5d5d5-1c51-45a2-88f9-7d8f414f2314 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f46d007e940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-15c373e4f88e> in <module>
     52 
     53 app.run_server(mode='jupyterlab', port = 9095, dev_tools_ui=True, #debug=True,
---> 54               dev_tools_hot_reload =True, threaded=True)

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_dash/jupyter_app.py in run_server(self, mode, width, height, inline_exceptions, **kwargs)
    317                 )
    318 
--> 319         wait_for_app()
    320 
    321         if JupyterDash._in_colab:

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py in wrapped_f(*args, **kw)
     47             @six.wraps(f)
     48             def wrapped_f(*args, **kw):
---> 49                 return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
     50 
     51             return wrapped_f

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py in call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
    210                 if not self._wrap_exception and attempt.has_exception:
    211                     # get() on an attempt with an exception should cause it to be raised, but raise just in case
--> 212                     raise attempt.get()
    213                 else:
    214                     raise RetryError(attempt)

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py in get(self, wrap_exception)
    245                 raise RetryError(self)
    246             else:
--> 247                 six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
    248         else:
    249             return self.value

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    701             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    702                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 703             raise value
    704         finally:
    705             value = None

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/retrying.py in call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
    198         while True:
    199             try:
--> 200                 attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
    201             except:
    202                 tb = sys.exc_info()

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_dash/jupyter_app.py in wait_for_app()
    305         )
    306         def wait_for_app():
--> 307             res = requests.get(alive_url).content.decode()
    308             if res != "Alive":
    309                 url = "http://{host}:{port}".format(

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     68 
     69     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 70     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     71 
     72 

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     54     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     55     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 56         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     57 
     58 

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    486         }
    487         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 488         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    489 
    490         return resp

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    607 
    608         # Send the request
--> 609         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    610 
    611         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/anaconda3/envs/epp_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    485                 raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    486 
--> 487             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    488 
    489         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='x86_64-conda-linux-gnu', port=9095): Max retries exceeded with url: /_alive_34d5d5d5-1c51-45a2-88f9-7d8f414f2314 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f46d007e940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

I am working on a centos linux machine inside a virtual environment.
Please suggest.

Apologies if this is a stupid mistake from my side.

Comment: For environment-related problems like this, it would be helpful to specify your execution environment and the version you are using so that the problem can be solved more quickly. From the error message, is your Internet connection working properly? Next, do you have jupyter_dash installed? Have you tried running `$ conda install -c conda-forge -c plotly jupyter-dash`?

Comment: Regarding your questions, the internet connection is proper and i had installed jupyter-dash. I found the answer from one of my seniors who had faced the same issue. It is because we have to explicitly specify the host and port when calling app_run like ```app.run_server(mode="inline", host = "localhost", port = 8080)```